# TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function No clue why error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

so I am getting the the error : TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function.
I am unsure why i made sure i exported the file, but I am a bit confused why. I think i linked it up correctly in my server file as well.

```
    const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(morgan('dev'))
require('dotenv').config()
const { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt")



app.use(bodyParser.json())
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/recipe', ()=> console.log('connected to database'))
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/authRouter'))
app.use("/api", jwt( {secret: process.env.SECRET, algorithms: ['HS256']}))
app.use('/api/recipe/', require('./routes/recipeRoutes'))
app.use('/api/public/'), require('./routes/publicDelete')
app.use('/api/comments/', require('./routes/commentRouter'))
app.use('/api/ingredients/', require('./routes/ingredRouter'))
app.use((err,req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(err)
    if(err.name ==='UnauthorizedError'){
        res.status(err.status)
    }
    return res.send({message:err.message})
})

app.listen(8000, ()=>{
    console.log('hello ')
})



 const express = require('express')

const publicDeleteRouter = express.Router()
const Recipe = require('../models/recipe')
const User = require('../models/user')

publicDeleteRouter.delete('/:recipeId', (req, res, next) =>{
    Recipe.findOneAndDelete({idMeal: req.params.recipeId, user: req.auth._id}, (err, deletedRecipe) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(idMeal)
            res.status(404)
            return next(err)
        }
        console.log('successfully deleted: ', deletedRecipe)
        return res.status(200).send(`Successfully deleted ${deletedRecipe}`)
    })
})
module.exports = publicDeleteRouter
```

Comment: Which line in particular triggers the error?

Comment: Oh, it's just a **typo** here... `app.use('/api/public/')`. Remove that `)`